# MKAnnotation undeclared

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mkannotation

I know there was a question about this before. However, I think a little bit noob because I can't get it solved.

I'm getting that error when trying this:

```
MKAnnotation *annotation = [[MKAnnotation alloc] initWithCoordinate:coordenada title:@"HELLO!"];
[mapa addAnnotation:annotation];
```

I also have the following method:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *) mapView: (MKMapView *) mapView viewForAnnotation: (id<MKAnnotation>) annotation
{
    MKPinAnnotationView *pin = (MKPinAnnotationView *) [self.mapa dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier: @"asdf"];
    if (pin == nil)
    {
        pin = [[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation: annotation reuseIdentifier: @"asdf"] autorelease];
    }
    else
    {
        pin.annotation = annotation;
    }
    pin.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorRed;
    pin.animatesDrop = YES;
    return pin;
}
```

And did the `#import < MapKit/MKAnnotation.h>` in header.

Any help please?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`MKAnnotation` is a protocol, not a class that you can instantiate.

Have you defined your own class that implements `MKAnnotation` and a `initWithCoordinate:title:` method?  If you have, use that class name and import its header file.

If you haven't created your own annotation class, you'll have to create one or you can use the pre-defined `MKPointAnnotation` class (in iOS 4+) instead:

```
MKPointAnnotation *annotation = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
annotation.coordinate = coordenada;
annotation.title = @"HELLO!";
[mapa addAnnotation:annotation];
[annotation release];
```

You'll also need to do the following:

- add the MapKit framework to the project
- add `#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>` at the top of the file
- set the `delegate` property (or outlet in IB) of the map view otherwise `viewForAnnotation` won't get called